# AjaxError on JPG upload in Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to build a Drupal 8 Open Social site, but I'm currently stuck on the following:

Whenever I want to upload a JPG or JPEG file I get the AjaxError below. PNG and GIF work perfectly fine.

```
AjaxError: 
Er is een AJAX HTTP fout opgetreden. 
HTTP-resultaatcode: 200 
Debug informatie volgt.
Pad: /stream?element_parents=field_post_image/widget/0&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=html
Statustekst: OK
Antwoordtekst:
```

And following the content in the path:

```
[{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":null,"data":"\u003Cdiv class=\u0022alert alert-danger alert-dismissible card-radius\u0022 role=\u0022alert\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 role=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022close\u0022 data-dismiss=\u0022alert\u0022 aria-label=\u0022Sluiten\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan aria-hidden=\u0022true\u0022\u003E\u0026times;\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/a\u003E\n      \u003Ch4 class=\u0022sr-only\u0022\u003EFoutmelding\u003C\/h4\u003E\n        Er is een fout opgetreden. Het bestand dat werd ge\u00fcpload is waarschijnlijk groter dan de maximum toegestane bestandsgrootte (64 MB).\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n","settings":null}]
```

Just to clarify, my minimum upload size is currently 64MB and the JPG/JPEG files I've tried to upload are below 1MB.

Could anyone point me to the right direction to be able to upload JPG/JPEG files?

Comment: What are the logs saying (drupal/server/php) ? If uploading png/gif works fine but not with jpg it's likely that you have a form validator restricting the possible file type to submit. But it could also be a server directive or php's mod_security rule `SecRule FILES_TMPNAMES "@inspectFile path/to/inspect_script.sh"`)

Comment: Hello Eric,

Thankyou for your response.

I've managed to get this out of my error.log:

[php7:notice] [pid 10668:tid 1900] [client ::1:58078] Error: Class 'lsolesen\\pel\\PelJpeg' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\profiles\\social\\modules\\contrib\\file_mdm\\file_mdm_exif\\src\\Plugin\\FileMetadata\\Exif.php on line 108

Comment: There is more but I can't get it to fit because it has alot of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to EricLauvault's hint I've managed to find my issue.

I had to use the composer command:

```
Composer Require lsolesen/pel
```

because my install was apparently missing its installment.